# When using CustomPaint, the splashColor and the highlightColor (in Inkwell) are pushed out

Tags: flutter, paint

`Inkwell` moves out while using `CustomPaint`.

Without Clicking:

[image]

While Clicking:

[image]

Button Snippet :

```
class _OpenCloseButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const _OpenCloseButton();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 15,
      height: 80,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.transparent),
      clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: _CustomPainter(context),
        // clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge, --> is there anything like that?
        child: Material(
          type: MaterialType.transparency,
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          child: InkWell(
            highlightColor: Colors.red,
            splashColor: Colors.red,
            onTap: () {},
            child: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios, size: 20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CustomPainter Snippet :

```
class _CustomPainter extends CustomPainter {
  const _CustomPainter(this.context);

  final BuildContext context;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final Paint paint = Paint()..color = context.theme.colorScheme.primary;
    final height = size.height;
    final width = size.width;
    final Path path = Path()
      ..moveTo(0, 0)
      ..lineTo(0, height)
      ..lineTo(width, height - 10)
      ..lineTo(width, 10)
      ..close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) => false;
}
```

I used clipbehavior, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Tried ClipRRect Widget? ClipRRect Widget prevents overflows in Container.

Comment: I didn't add the example here to keep it longer, but I normally use the quadraticBezierTo method. Can I use quadraticBezierTo in ClipRRect?